# Where are the logs for Homebrew service `dnscrypt-proxy`?

Tags: homebrew, launchd

Where are the logs for the `dnscrypt-proxy` Homebrew service?

There are no logs in these directories, or the directories don't even exist:

- `/usr/local/var/log/`
- `/opt/homebrew/var/log`
- `$(find /opt/homebrew -type d -name log)`

The daemon is in an error state, but there are no logs:

```
$ brew services info dnscrypt-proxy
dnscrypt-proxy (homebrew.mxcl.dnscrypt-proxy)
Running: ✘
Loaded: ✔
Schedulable: ✘

$ brew services list
Name           Status       User   File
dnscrypt-proxy error  65280 $USER  ~/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.dnscrypt-proxy.plist
```

Comment: Did you look into the plist?

Comment: Have you tried /private/var/log/com.apple.xpc.launchd/launchd.log ?